# MySQL fetch command isn't returning data

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Want the PHP script to pull all data from the database and **display** it on screen. But can't find the most efficient method to display the records without using the $query_params variable as it generates an error with the parameters in but cannot run without an array?

```
//initial query
$query = "Select * FROM tbl_data";

//execute query
try {
$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Database Error!";
die(json_encode($response));
}
```

And here is the display code

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
if ($rows) {
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Post Available!";
$response["posts"]   = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $post             = array();
    $post["username"] = $row["username"];
    $post["title"]    = $row["title"];
    $post["message"]  = $row["message"];
```

I would be really grateful if you could help, thank you!

Comment: Why do you use prepared statement, if there is no parameter in the query?

Comment: Probably a good point to add actually, this is code I've made based on a tutorial, they left the parameter in(I presume in error) but I don't know what statement to use instead of this one as I am learning PHP with Android at the moment

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: ^^ `PDO::query()` is appropriate _for this specific use case_ where you have _no input_ passed to the query.  But since you are learning, I have to clarify the earlier comments that it is very important to use `prepare()/execute()` the way you are doing if `$query_params` would have any values in it. What specifically is the error generated? Since you have no named or `?` placeholders in the query, it should work just fine if you omit `$query_params` from `execute()`. Is that an empty array?

Comment: Yes the array is currently empty as I wanted to pull all data from the database without taking any user input